# Transfer from two columns to one column then to two column in text with "twocolumn" parameter on one page

Tags: floats, two-column

It is feasible to transfer from two columns to one column or from one column to two columns in text or with figures or tables based on the `twocolumn` parameters on one page. But Transfer from two columns to one column and then to two columns on one page is a question. For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,lipsum,balance}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\par\balance
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    {
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Example image}
    }
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\par
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

How to move the content of the second page to the bottom of the first page keeping the figure in the middle of the first page? I don't know how to achieve this effect.

Comment: Is there a reason the image **has to be** directly below the first paragraph? As you may know, Latex normaly uses floating figures for a better typesetted result. In `twocolumn` documents you can easily achieve this with the `figure*` environment.

Comment: @lukeflo I this the root cause is `twocolumn` is not compatible with `[h]` parameter of floats.

Answer (score 3):

To really switch between different numbers of columns, you could use [package `multicol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{centering}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \captionof{figure}{Example image}
\end{centering}
\end{minipage}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: using multicols]

But usually I would suggest to use a `figure*` to float the figure to the top of the next page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example image}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: with figure*]

You can also trick with mixing native `twocolumn` mode and `multicols`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,lipsum,balance,multicol}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
{\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{multicols}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Example image}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}}%
]
\par
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would not recommend to do so.

Comment: `multicol` has two defects. 1. Can't add line numbers at the outside margins of the two columns; 2. Not compatible with the `float` environment. As these these two defects, I transfer from `multicol` to `twocolumn`. Thanks.

Comment: @Y.zeng I can only answer, what has been asked. 1. You question does not show, that you need line numbers and that this is your real problem. 2. Your question does not use a `float` environment. However inside `multicols` star floats like `figure*` and `table*` are supported (see section 2.4 of the manual). My answer shows an alternative with ending the `multicols` environment, printing the figure and start a new one. 3. I've also shown an alternative using native twocolumn mode, but moving the figure. Because using the native twocolumn mode with h floats spanning two columns is not possible.

Comment: Yes. Your way does good. `multicol` support `figure*` and `table*` to accross the two or more columns, but inside one column, it doesn't.

Comment: @Y.zeng But you can place non-floating figures inside a column, if you need. However this is more manual work than using a float. But you cannot have everything.

Comment: Placing no-floating figures inside one column may cause the bottom of the column to contain too much space

Comment: @Y.zeng As I already said: However this is more manual work than using a float.

Comment: Yes. I think the second way you provided is the best now. It can only work on a new page, not in the middle of the page. It is a little pity.